# Is Rspec controller test usually too long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My spec/controllers/decidings_controller_spec.rb is below.

```
RSpec.describe DecidingsController, type: :controller do
 describe '#create' do
     before do
       @deciding=build(:deciding_consenting_false)
     end
     context 'correct_user login' do
         before do 
             login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
         end
         it 'creates with deciding +1' do
           expect{post :create , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(1)
         end
         it 'redirects to undertking' do
             post :create , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id
             expect(response).to redirect_to @deciding.undertaking
         end
     end
     context 'incorrect_user login' do
         before do 
             @user=create(:user)
             login_user(@user)
         end
         it 'creates with deciding 0' do
           expect{post :create , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(0)
         end
         it 'redirects to undertking' do
             post :create , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id
             expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
         end
     end
end
describe '#destroy' do
    context 'before deciding consent' do
        before do
            @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_false)
        end
        context 'correct_user login' do
            before do
               login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
            end
            it 'destroy with deciding -1' do
                expect{delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding , asking_id: @deciding}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(-1)
            end
            it 'redirects undertaking show' do
                delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id
                expect(response).to redirect_to @deciding.undertaking
            end
        end
        context 'incorrect_user login' do
            before do
                user=create(:user)
                login_user(user)
            end
            it 'destroy with deciding -1' do
                expect{delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding , asking_id: @deciding}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(0)
            end
            it 'redirects undertaking show' do
                delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id
                expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
            end
        end
    end
    context ' if after deciding consent( should #before_consent)' do
        before do
            @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_true)
        end
        context 'correct_user login' do
            before do
               login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
            end
            it 'destroy with deciding 0' do
                expect{delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding , asking_id: @deciding}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(0)
            end
            it 'redirects undertaking show' do
                delete :destroy , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id
                expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
            end
        end
    end
 end
 describe '#consent' do
    context 'correct_user login' do
        before do
            @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_false)
            login_user(@deciding.undertaking.user)
        end
        it 'consenting changes true' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            @deciding.reload
            expect(@deciding.consenting).to eq true
        end
        it 'redirect_to undertaking' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            expect(response).to redirect_to @deciding.undertaking
        end  
    end
    context 'asking user login' do
        before do
            @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_false)
            login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
        end
        it 'consenting not changes true' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            @deciding.reload
            expect(@deciding.consenting).to eq false               
        end
        it 'redirect_to root' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
    context 'incorrect_user login' do
        before do
            @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_false)
            @user=create(:user)
            login_user(@user)
        end
        it 'consenting not changes true' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            @deciding.reload
            expect(@deciding.consenting).to eq false           
        end
        it 'redirect_to root' do
            patch :consent , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id
            expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end
describe '#deciding_cancel' do
    context 'correct_user login' do
        context 'asking user login' do
            context 'should #after_consent' do
                before do
                    @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_true)
                    login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
                end

            end
            context 'should not before consent' do
                before do
                    @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_false)
                    login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
                end                   
            end
            context 'should #before_finish' do
                before do
                    @deciding=create(:deciding_consenting_true)
                    login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
                end

            end
            context 'should not before finish' do
                before do
                    @deciding=create(:deciding_after_finish)
                    login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
                end                   
            end
        end
        context 'undertaking user login' do
        end
    end
    context 'incorrect_user login' do
        before do
            @user=create(:user)
        end
    end
end


describe '#deciding_cancel' do
    context 'correct_user login' do
    end
    context 'incorrect_user login' do
    end
end
describe '#deciding_cancel' do
    context 'correct_user login' do
    end
    context 'incorrect_user login' do
    end
end
```

end

My Decidingscontroller has many before_action for conditional branching. so My spec file becomes too long.
Is there other way in this case? If there is other way to make the program short, please tell me.

Anyway, My controllers/decidings_controller.rb is below.

```
   class DecidingsController < ApplicationController

#correct_user?
before_action :authenticate_user! 
before_action :asking_user!, only: [:create , :destroy , :asking_finish , :finish_cancel ]
before_action :undertaking_user!, only: [:consent , :undertaking_finish]
before_action :asking_or_undertaking_user! , only: [:deciding_cancel,:deciding_cancel_consent , :deciding_cancel_refuse]
before_action :reverse_user! ,only: [:deciding_cancel_consent , :deciding_cancel_refuse]

#流れ
before_action :before_consent , only: [:destroy]
before_action :after_consent , only: [:deciding_cancel ,:deciding_cancel_consent , :deciding_cancel_refuse, :undertaking_finish , :asking_finish , :finish_cancel ]
before_action :before_finish , only: [:deciding_cancel ,:deciding_cancel_consent , :deciding_cancel_refuse]
before_action :after_deciding_cancel , only: [:deciding_cancel_consent , :deciding_cancel_refuse]
before_action :after_undertaking_finish , only: [:asking_finish , :finish_cancel]


def create
    asking=Asking.find(params[:asking_id])
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    deciding=Deciding.new(asking_id: asking.id , undertaking_id: undertaking.id)
    if deciding.save
        flash[:success] = "契約作成に成功しました。"
        redirect_to undertaking
    else
        flash[:alert] = "契約作成に失敗しました。"
        redirect_to undertaking
    end
end
def destroy
  asking=Asking.find(params[:asking_id])
  undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
  asking.deciding.destroy
  flash[:info]='契約申し込みをキャンセルしました。'
  redirect_to undertaking
end
def consent
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    if undertaking.deciding
        undertaking.deciding.update(consenting: true)
        flash[:success] = "契約が成立しました。"
        redirect_to undertaking
    else
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
def deciding_cancel
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.update(cancel: true , cancel_userid: current_user.id)
    flash[:success] = "途中終了リクエストを送信しました。"
    redirect_to undertaking
end
def deciding_cancel_consent
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.destroy        
    flash[:success] = "契約が途中終了されました。"
    redirect_to undertaking
end
def deciding_cancel_refuse
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.update(cansel: false , cansel_userid: nil)       
    flash[:success] = "契約の途中終了を却下しました。"
    redirect_to undertaking
end
def undertaking_finish
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.update(finish_undertaking: true)
    flash[:success] = "納品が完了しました。"
    redirect_to undertaking
end
def finish_cancel
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.update(finish_undertaking: false)
    flash[:success] = "再納品リクエストを送信しました。"
    redirect_to undertaking
end
def asking_finish
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    undertaking.deciding.update(finish_asking: true)
    flash[:success] = "納品が成立しました。"
    redirect_to asking
end


private

def asking_user!
    asking=Asking.find(params[:asking_id])
    unless asking.user==current_user
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
def undertaking_user!
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    unless undertaking.user==current_user
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end     
def asking_or_undertaking_user!
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    unless current_user==undertaking.user || current_user==undertaking.asking.user
      refirect_to root_path
    end
end
def reverse_user!
     undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
     if current_user.id == undertaking.deciding.cansel_userid
         refirect_to root_path
     end
end

def before_consent
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    if undertaking.deciding.consenting
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end


def after_consent
    asking=Asking.find(params[:asking_id])
    unless asking.deciding.consenting
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def before_finish
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    if undertaking.deciding.finish_undertaking
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def after_deciding_cancel
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    unless undertaking.deciding.cancel
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def after_undertaking_finish
    undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])
    unless undertaking.deciding.finish_undertaking
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

end

Please help me...

Comment: Not that long at all. You should see some of my Rspecs!

Comment: there's a lot of `undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id])`. you can probably change that to another `before_action` call.  You may also want to consider eager loading stuff but from a quick read of your code, you're only working on 1 record of undertaking/asking on each action so eager loading will have a small effect.

Comment: oh and rspec tests are usually longer than the files they're testing because of stubs/mocks and expectations so don't sweat it.

Comment: Oh ,thank you for your comment! I feel relieved! and I see! I fix undertaking=Undertaking.find(params[:undertaking_id]) ! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not worry about long controller and spec files in Rails.

These files tend to get very long and the usual advice of keeping classes and methods short does not necessarily apply for controllers and their specs.

For example, in our production system `user_controller.rb` is 8500 lines long and the corresponding `user_controller_spec.rb` is 7000 lines long.

This is the length of our top 10 controllers

```
1285 app/controllers/*********_controller.rb
1430 app/controllers/***********_controller.rb
1444 app/controllers/****_controller.rb
1950 app/controllers/****_controller.rb
1994 app/controllers/********_controller.rb
2530 app/controllers/***********_controller.rb
2697 app/controllers/*********_controller.rb
2998 app/controllers/*****_controller.rb
3134 app/controllers/application_controller.rb
8737 app/controllers/users_controller.rb
```

Comment: Oh , that's very long!! Thank you , I feel relieved!

Comment: Good to know about size of controller tests

Comment: do you still have 8500 lines in your controller?